# Render a template after a specific route by using system plugin

Tags: templates, plugin-events

I am facing a problem to render a template after hitting a specific route.

Let me describe it a bit. I have a template structure like-

```
templates
|__mytemplate
|__|__index.php
|__|__component.php
|__|__myfile.php
```

Now from a `system` plugin, I want to render just the `myfile.php` with its own `scripts` and `styles` when it hits the route `index.php?option=com_ajax&mytemplate=1`.

The `myfile.php` is a simple file.

```
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
</head>
<body class="contentpane">
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</body>
```

Which I found to render a template file is like-

```
$doc->render(false, ['template' => 'mytemplate', 'file' => 'myfile.php']);
```

But the problem is, I don't get in which event is perfect for rendering the `Document` and I don't want any template specific styles/scripts. In other words, I just want to parse and render the `myfile.php` with its own styles/scripts.

Then which is the best event where I can attach the styles/scripts and render the `myfile.php`.

Answer (score 0):

This template allows you to output as blank:

https://github.com/Lyquix/tpl_lyquix/blob/2.x/custom.dist.php

If you look at the **tmpl_mode** option for clues.

Also - this code could perhaps work in identifying the component (com_ajax) in your index.php:

```
//ECHO COMPONENT TYPE ()
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;



if(($jinput->get('option') == 'com_ajax')  && ($app->getTemplate('template')->id == 1)) {
  //load com_ajax CSS 
echo 'load com_ajax CSS';

 } else {

echo 'load normal CSS';
  
}
```